# Binding Python Bluetooth Socket to Virtual Port

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, bluetooth, node-red, rfcomm

I have created a Bluetooth communication between Arduino and Raspberry Pi. I am using [D-BUS API](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/) that is used by [BlueZ](https://github.com/bluez/bluez) to pair and trust, and [Python socket module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) to establish a **rfcomm communication**.

I want to access the data I receive from Arduino on [Node-RED](https://nodered.org/) on Pi. Unfortunately Node-RED do not have any classic Bluetooth nodes that are under active development. So, what can I do is using [serial input node](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-node-serialport).

If I use deprecated command line tool **rfcomm** to connect(Ex. `sudo rfcomm connect hci0 00:11:12:34:56:78 1` ), it creates an **rfcomm channel** bound to **/dev/rfcomm0**. Than I can use **serial input node** and access to data in Node-RED. However, I want to avoid using this deprecated tool.

However, if I connect via **Python socket module** as below:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH,socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
s.bind(some_address, some_port)
s.connect(some_address, some_port)
```

No virtual device/port such as **/dev/rfcomm0** is created. Hence, I cannot access the data from Node-RED.

So the question is how can bind the socket created by python socket to any virtual port? Where this rfcomm channel is located exactly? It must be bound to a virtual network port in some way?

When I examine the rfcomm tool's [source file](https://github.com/bluez/bluez/blob/master/tools/rfcomm.c), I feel like I need to dive into some OS programming to do what I want.

Comment: Why do you want to use Python? You should be able to work directly with the bluetooth from NodeJS and write a custom Node-RED node to do it.

Comment: I am very familiar with Python, not with Node-RED. Do you have any example customized node where you, pair, trust, and then establish rfcomm connection over bluetooth in Node-RED? I have tried already available bluetooth nodes, but couldn't succeed yet.